# Magento: Using different footers for different page layouts

Tags: php, magento

I've tried various tutorials but I can't get this to work.

Basically, I want to have a different footer on my homepage.  I've setup two page layouts and have applied them to the cms pages fine.

So in the homepage layout I refer to...

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_home') ?>
```

And on all the other pages this...

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_alt') ?>
```

Pretty simple!
Then in the page xml I've amended the part which refers to the footer as follows...

```
            <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer_alt" as="footer_alt" template="page/html/footer_alt.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
        </block>


          <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer_home" as="footer_home" template="page/html/footer_home.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
                <label>Page Footer2</label>
                <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
        </block>
```

I think this is where the problem lies. With the above all pages show the 'footer_alt' footer and I'm not sure why.

I can confirm that 'page/html/footer_alt.phtml' and 'page/html/footer_home.phtml' are setup fine.

I hope that makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the rendering call to getChildHtml in some sort os special unique character?  Like `###<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_home') ?>###`?  Based on the information above, it seems unlikely that a call to render `footer_html` would render `footer_alt` — you may be editing the wrong files.

Comment: The files I'm editing are the main layout template file, the page.xml file and the subsequent footer_alt.phtml and footer_home.phtml.

Answer (score 8):

All of these answers are *way* too complex for what is a straightforward solution. Rewriting is overkill. Rewriting Magento core, even if done properly, should *always* set off alarms and immediately compel that developer to thoroughly read the Magento source. In my experience, every Magento heartache is accompanied by a cryptic but entirely gratifying solution. This is one of those heartaches with a gratifying solution.

It comes as no surprise that Magento arbitrarily decided to ensure that the footer templates do not generate a unique cache key. This means that the footer cannot be different depending on the section of the site loaded; to be clear, it actually can, but *only* if the block cache is disabled. The block cache should never be disabled, though, so ultimately, this is tantamount to being restricted to a single footer across the entire site.

There are legitimate use cases for wanting a different footer in different parts of the site. For example, in the checkout: the checkout should be immersive and distraction-free. However, the moment any page on the site is hit, the footer from those pages will be cached, and then the checkout will display that same footer.

Solutions described here require either a core rewrite, which is no good, or some other conditional check, which will not reasonably scale beyond a few conditions.

My solution is simple: add a cacheKey to the new template. Target the layout handle for the given page, reference the footer, set the template, and then add the cacheKey. This is just standard Magento layout XML. This layout XML changes the footer on the onepage checkout--and *only* on the onepage checkout. Furthermore, caching will continue to work for every unique footer defined in this way.

```
    <checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="footer">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>linusmoneymaker/page/html/checkout-footer.phtml</template>
            </action>
            <action method="setCacheKey">
                <key>your-own-unique-cache-key-for-linus-moneymaker</key>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index>
```

This works for the following reason. Here is the source for `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php`, which handles all the block caching:

```
/**
 * Get Key for caching block content
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCacheKey()
{
    if ($this->hasData('cache_key')) {
        return $this->getData('cache_key');
    }
    /**
     * don't prevent recalculation by saving generated cache key
     * because of ability to render single block instance with different data
     */
    $key = $this->getCacheKeyInfo();
    //ksort($key);  // ignore order
    $key = array_values($key); // ignore array keys
    $key = implode('|', $key);
    $key = sha1($key);
    return $key;
}
```

Notice that if a `cacheKey` is defined, that one will take precedence over the one that will be generated from the `getCacheKeyInfo` method in `app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Footer.php`, which does not produce a per-template unique `cacheKey`. By providing a `cacheKey` from the layout XML, Magento effectively abandons the default, non-unique footer `cacheKey` in favour of the one provided manually through the layout XML for the given part of the site.

Not only is this the proper way, but it scales infinitely. Every page on the site could realistically define its own footer.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for you problem should be magento's block cache.
Like the header the footer is cached by default and
the cache key does not include the template

to verify its a cache problem try this first:

Check if the block cache is enabled.
Then navigate to your page. The footer on the first page should be on any of the following.
So if your first page view is your alt footer it will be on any other page and vise versa.

if the problem is the cache you should be able to solve this
by rewriting the "Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer" and
modify getCacheKeyInfo() to include the template like this

```
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    return array(
        'PAGE_FOOTER',
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
        (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure(),
        Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
        Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn(),
        $this->getTemplate()
    );
}
```

this should solve your problem.

Comment: How do I know if block caching is enabled? Where do I find the Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer file? Thanks.

Comment: you can check if the block cache is enable by going to your magento backend and check it unter System->Cache Management you should find a row named "Blocks HTML output" if its active the block cache is on.

The "Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer" Class can be found under:
"app/code/core/Mage\Page/Block/Html/Footer.php"

Answer (score 0):

1. Create 2 static Blocks named "home_page_footer" and "inner_page_footer".
2. Open footer.phtml and place the following code.

   ```
   <?php $home = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier(); ?>
   <?php if ($home):?>     
   <div style="clear:both;">
       <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('home_page_footer')->toHtml(); ?>
   </div>
   <?php else: ?>      
   <div style="clear:both;">
       <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('inner_page_footer')->toHtml(); ?>
   </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
   ```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Although this seems like the simplest solution I can't get it to work.  All pages show the home_page_footer.  I've cleared cache and index.

Comment: Please Re-Check, Magento Version: 1.7.0.2. It Works Perfect for me.

Comment: DO I need to change this? What should cms/page be for my homepage? The URL key? <?php $home = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier(); ?>

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();  this is the identified of magento home page. I just simply use if else statement for indicating home page and inner page and place home page and inner page script inside the static blocks. that's it.The file location, to add this script is "app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\footer.phtml". thanks

Comment: OK thanks.  I still can't get this to work.  So there are no changes to any xml files in addition to this?